# Omitting NA/NaN from Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to output the rows of a matrix but I want to omit NaN and NAs.  The following simple example illustrates:

```
 m <- matrix(c(1,2,NA,NaN,1,-1,-1,1,9,3),5)
for (i in 1:nrow(m)) { 
  cat(paste(sprintf('%d:%f', 1:ncol(m), m[i, ]), collapse=' '), "\n") 
 }
```

and the output is this:

```
1:1.000000 2:-1.000000 
1:2.000000 2:-1.000000 
1:NA 2:1.000000 
1:NaN 2:9.000000 
1:1.000000 2:3.000000
```

but I want:

```
1:1.000000 2:-1.000000 
1:2.000000 2:-1.000000 
2:1.000000 
2:9.000000 
1:1.000000 2:3.000000
```

I've been trying various combinations of `!is.na` but no joy.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is.finite`

```
 m <- matrix(c(1,2,NA,NaN,1,-1,-1,1,9,3),5)
f <- apply(m,1,function(x) sum(is.finite(x))) #how many finite in each row
for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
cat(paste(sprintf('%d:%f', 1:f[i], m[i, ][is.finite(m[i,])]), collapse=' '), "\n")  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,NA,NaN,1,-1,-1,1,9,3),5)
for (i in 1:nrow(m)) { 
  row <- m[i,]
  row <- row[!is.na(row)]
  cat(paste(sprintf('%d:%f', 1:length(row), row), collapse=' '), "\n") 
}
```

Here is a solution using is.na().

Output:

```
1:1.000000 2:-1.000000 
1:2.000000 2:-1.000000 
1:1.000000 
1:9.000000 
1:1.000000 2:3.000000
```